# Convergence of expected value of the function when it has the Lipschitz continuous gradient property?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, stochastic-analysis, smooth-functions

A differentiable function is said to have the Lipschitz continuous gradient property if the following holds true for some $L>0$:
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|,\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

The above property immediately results in the following:

$$f(y) \leq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x) , y-x \rangle + \frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2 \quad \forall x,y$$

Using the above property if we have $x_{k+1}=x_{k}-\gamma \nabla f(x_k) $ and $\gamma <2/L$ we get the following:
$$
f(x_{k+1}) + \left(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\frac{L}{2}\right)\|x_{k+1}-x_{k}\|^2 \leq f(x_{k})
$$
Assuming that $f(x)$ is bounded bellow, the above means sequence of $\{f(x_k)\}_{ k \geq 0}$ is convergent.

Now define $x_{k+1}=x_{k}-\gamma g_k $ where $\mathbb{E}[g_k]=\nabla f(x_k)$.

**Question**: Can we show $\{\mathbb{E}[f(x_{k})
]\}_{ k \geq 0}$ is convergent by finding a good $\gamma$ and assuming a condition like $\mathbb{E}[\|\nabla f(x_{k})-g_k\|^2] \leq \sigma^2$ or $\mathbb{E}[\|g_k\|^2] \leq \sigma^2$ for some $\sigma > 0$?

**My try**: I used $\mathbb{E}[\|\nabla f(x_{k})-g_k\|^2] \leq \sigma^2$ and varying step-length.

$$
\begin{split}
f(x_{k+1}) &\leq f(x_k) + \langle \nabla f(x_k) , x_{k+1}-x_k \rangle + \frac{L}{2}\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|^2\\
f(x_{k+1}) &\leq f(x_k) - \gamma_k \langle \nabla f(x_k) , g_k \rangle + \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\|g_k\|^2 \\
f(x_{k+1}) &\leq f(x_k) - \gamma_k \langle g_k , g_k \rangle 
+ \gamma_k \langle g_k - \nabla f(x_k), g_k \rangle
+\frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\|g_k\|^2
\end{split}
$$
Let $\delta_k=g_k-\nabla f(x_k)$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
f(x_{k+1}) & \leq f(x_k) - \gamma_k \langle g_k , g_k \rangle 
+ \gamma_k \langle \delta_k, g_k \rangle
+\frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\|g_k\|^2\\
\bigg(\gamma_k - \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\bigg)\|g_k\|^2 
& \leq f(x_k) - f(x_{k+1}) 
+ \gamma_k \langle \delta_k, g_k - \nabla f(x_k) \rangle
+ \gamma_k \langle \delta_k, \nabla f(x_k) \rangle\\
\bigg(\gamma_k - \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\bigg)\|g_k\|^2 
& \leq f(x_k) - f(x_{k+1}) 
+ \gamma_k \| \delta_k\|^2
+ \gamma_k \langle \delta_k, \nabla f(x_k) \rangle
\end{split}
$$
By taking the expectation with respect to $g_k$ we have:

$$
\begin{split}
\bigg(\gamma_k - \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\bigg)\mathbb{E}[\|g_k\|^2 ]
& \leq 
\mathbb{E}[f(x_k)] - \mathbb{E}[f(x_{k+1})] 
+ \gamma_k \mathbb{E}[\| \delta_k\|^2]
+ \mathbb{E}[\gamma_k \langle \delta_k, \nabla f(x_k) \rangle]\\
(\gamma_k - \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2})\mathbb{E}[\|g_k\|^2 ]
& \leq 
\mathbb{E}[f(x_k)] - \mathbb{E}[f(x_{k+1})] 
+ \gamma_k \sigma^2
\end{split}
$$

Summing over $k$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\bigg(\gamma_k - \frac{L\gamma_k^2}{2}\bigg)\mathbb{E}[\|g_k\|^2 ]
\leq 
\mathbb{E}[f(x_1)] - \mathbb{E}[f(x_{N+1})] 
+ \gamma_k N\sigma^2
$$

Is there any way to show that on average 2-norm of the stochastic gradient, that is, $\mathbb{E}[\|g_k\|^2 ]$, decreases?